# Message to user while page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

I have an action that creates mysqldump when user clicks on backup button. When user click on backup , he has to wait a couple of seconds before something shows up. I'd like to
give users a message while they are waiting.

What are preferred ways to solve out this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="spinner" style="display:none;margin-top:10px;">
  Taking backup of file.. <img alt="Spinner" src="/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
</div>


<% form_remote_tag(:url => {:controller => "controller_name",:action => "backup"},
    :before => %(Element.show('spinner')),
    :success => %(Element.hide('spinner'))) do -%>
   <%= label_tag "new_back_up_file", "Add New Backup File :" %> </div>
   <%= text_field_tag "add_new_backup_file",nil %> </div>
   <%= submit_tag " ",:class => "backup"%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Show a dialog box that blocks the user interface (UI)
2. Execute the backup through an Ajax call
3. On completion of the ajax call, remove the dialog

For an example of a UI blocking plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

Comment: +1 jQuery block isn't necessary though. Requirement is just to show a message. A simple dialog box would also work.

Comment: Can you please explain it with example ?